# Dealing with non complete cases and imputing?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data_frame('col1' = c(NA, 1, 2), 'col2' = c(34, NA, 44), 'indicator' = c(1,1,0))
```

I have used `complete.cases` to flag all the incomplete cases.

Now what I want to do is to replace NA values with `10` if `indicator == 1` and `0` otherwise per each column.

Trying to do this with `apply` and `MARGIN = 2`.

Please advise how to perform such task.

Comment: `df$col1[is.na(df$col1)] <- ifelse(df$indicator == 1, 10, 0)`; and the same for column 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at` from `dplyr`.  Specify the columns of interest in the `vars` argument of `mutate_at`, inside the `funs`, create a logical condition with `case_when` to replace with values that met with the condition

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("col\\d+")), 
       funs(case_when(is.na(.) & as.logical(indicator)~ 10, 
                      is.na(.) & !indicator ~ 0,  
                      TRUE ~ .)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   col1  col2 indicator
#    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1    10    34         1
# 2     1    10         1 
# 3     2    44         0
```

---

This can also be done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
for(j in names(df)[1:2]) {
  i1 <- is.na(df[[j]]) 
  i2 <-  as.logical(df[['indicator']])

  set(df, i = which(i1 & i2), j = j, value = 10)
  set(df, i = which(i1 & !i2), j = j, value = 0)
 }
```

---

If we want the maximum of the column instead of 10 to replace the `NA` values where 'indicator' is 1, use `max`

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("col\\d+")), 
       funs(case_when(is.na(.) & as.logical(indicator)~ max(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                      is.na(.) & !indicator ~ 0,  
                      TRUE ~ .)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  col1  col2 indicator
#  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     2    34         1
#2     1    44         1
#3     2    44         0
```

Comment: This is not doing what I want, I want to run only on NA's. Your solution is great but it eliminates all other numbers.

Comment: @steves  It is running only on NAs

Comment: But I don't see where 1, 2, 34, 44, the data frame is only 0's and 10's

Comment: @steves I was confused earlier about the condition, then I changed it before you commented

Comment: And if I want the maximum of the column instead of 10 how can I achieve this?

Comment: By asking a new, different question.

Comment: @akrun can you please tell me how to make it max of column instead of 10?

Comment: @akrun as always your answers are genius my pleasure to learn from your great answers!

Comment: Where is the advantage over base R (speed?).

Comment: @jan `data.table` method should be faster, but when we use `tidyverse`, it is not really the speed that people opt for, but it could be the easiness of understanding etc.  But, I really don't have any preference with various methods or with different softwares as well

Comment: @akrun: Thanks for the clarification (and keep up the very well written answers)!

Answer (score 2):

While you already have your answer, you could very well use `apply` as asked in the question:

```
df <- data.frame('col1' = c(NA, 1, 2), 
                 'col2' = c(34, NA, 44), 
                 'indicator' = c(1,1,0), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

# columns in question
cols <- colnames(df)[!colnames(df) %in% c('indicator')]

# apply it row-wise
# using a nested ifelse call
df[cols] <- apply(df[cols], 2, function(x) {
  y <- ifelse(is.na(x),
              ifelse(df$indicator == 1, 10, 0),
              x)
  y
})
df
```

Or with less whitespace:

```
df[cols] <- apply(df[cols], 2, function(x) {
  (y <- ifelse(is.na(x), ifelse(df$indicator == 1, 10, 0), x))
})
```

This yields

```
  col1 col2 indicator
1   10   34         1
2    1   10         1
3    2   44         0
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! I will use it too.
Simple and genius :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple and clear:

```
df$col1[ is.na(df$col1) ] <- ifelse(df$indicator == 1, 10, 0)
df$col2[ is.na(df$col2) ] <- ifelse(df$indicator == 1, 10, 0)
```

If you have many columns, just use a for loop:

```
for (col in c("col1", "col2")) { 
  df[ is.na(df[[col]]), col] <- ifelse(df$indicator == 1, 10, 0)
}
```

Comment: Or use `apply()` for several columns.